# socket.io switch to ajax from client side

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Is it possible to change preffered io.transports from client side? For some reasons some clients cant use websockets, so I want to make button which changes prefferef transports list. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io client automatically determines the available transports and there is an option of `try multiple transports` which is true by default and it tries all available transports before finally giving up. You should enable all the transports on server side like this:

```
io.set('transports', [
 'websocket'
,'flashsocket'
,'htmlfile'
,'xhr-polling'
,'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

However you can enable a transport on client side as:

```
socket = io.connect(HOSTNAME, {
  transports: ['xhr-polling']
});
```